# Webmastertools: site has no hreflang tags after implemented hreflang tag

Tags: wordpress, tags, google-search-console, hreflang

I have an issue with my website.

I have implemented below language tags on my website and I am targeting the website in Indonesian and English language for users on Indonesia, Malaysia, and Australia

zahiraccounting.com/ is Default page, redirects according to the IP to:

zahiraccounting.com/id/ (language: Indonesian, Target Country: Indonesia)

zahiraccounting.com/id-en/ (language: English, Target Country: Indonesia)

zahiraccounting.com/en-my/ (language: English, Target Country: Malaysia)

zahiraccounting.com/en-au/ (language: English, Target Country: Australia)

I put my code before  on all those websites *(the websites based on wordpress, i put it in header.php)*:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://zahiraccounting.com" hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://zahiraccounting.com/id" hreflang="id" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://zahiraccounting.com/id-en" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://zahiraccounting.com/en-my" hreflang="en-my" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://zahiraccounting.com/en-au" hreflang="en-au" />
```

Now I can see an error in Google webmaster mentioned below:

> Your site has no hreflang tags.
>
> Google uses hreflang tags to match the user's language preference to
>   the right variation of your pages.

How can i fix this?

Comment: same problem. or mb it will be solved after some time automatically? is it ok for you now or not?